# Where can I find a description of math language symbols?

Tags: notation, definition

I am reading math articles. I meet math symbols.

For example $\exists$ or $\forall$.

For example for "For any a exist e that" can be rewriten as: $\forall a \exists e$

Where can I find full description of this math language?

Comment: The references in [the tag wiki for the notation tag](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/notation/info) may be useful.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols

Comment: Mathematical Operators: http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2200.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think for a "Full Description", you need a textbook, but there are plently of decent resources online.

A rather terse setting out of the symbols used in logical notation exists here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols

For a slightly more instructive list, this seems rather good:
http://www.philosophy-index.com/logic/symbolic/

And here's a Symbolic Cheat Sheet:
http://cl.indiana.edu/~md7/15/614/misc/symbols.pdf

But look, I'm basically doing your google search for you - these particular symbols seem to be all to do with [Symbolic Logic](http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/symbolic_logic.html) - if you are studying other areas of math, there will no doubt be other notations, and other resources online for you to discover.

A good resource that enumerates (and, importantly for googling stuff, names) a wide range of math notation is this Latex reference: https://reu.dimacs.rutgers.edu/Symbols.pdf

It sets out all manner of symbols and squiggles, along with the text-command used to render them in Latex. If nothing else, this could provide you with a name to google and learn about the meaning of a specific symbol.

Unhelpfully, depending on the [area of math](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OmJ-4B-mS-Y) you're studying, there can be "regional" dialects - for example, sometimes, surrounding something with single-bars $|Z|$ can mean taking the `absolute` value of an expression, but in set notation, it can refer to the cardinality/count of elements in a set.

Learning the local customs of mathematical notation can take time, but is usually interesting and rewarding.

Answer (score 0):

The International Organization for Standardization (aka ISO), has published the ISO 80000-2 which gives general information about mathematical signs and symbols, their meanings, verbal equivalents and applications.

The recommendations in ISO 80000-2 are intended mainly for used in the natural science and technology, but also applies to the areas where mathematics is used.

The ISO 80000-2 comes with a cost to reading it but you should be able to find a copy of pdf if you look harder in the internet like I did but this one is published in 2009: https://people.engr.ncsu.edu/jwilson/files/mathsigns.pdf

If you want something freshly published: https://www.iso.org/standard/64973.html